# How can I register a cocoa app to receive remote notifications to update the UI?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have simplified the scenario for explanation purposes. It is an employee check-in and out payroll system. I have 2 desktop stations with two different OS X Apps that I have created:

1. Station one has an app that updates the database on the server when an employee checks-in late. This employee is flagged for the day.
2. Station two has an app for managers that lets them to specific managerial tasks, but would like to know who has checked-in late into the building.

How can I update the app UI on station 2 without polling to the server periodically? I find this to be inneficient and believe that push notifications will help here. In iOS, an app can register itself to receive push notifications, so that when a server sends a notification and an app is in the foreground, the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method is called so that the UI can be updated accordingly based on the notification object.

How can the same be achieved for a cocoa app?

Answer (score 3):

Receiving push notification on OS X is very similar to iOS.
You register your app by calling:

```
[NSApp registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:NSRemoteNotificationTypeBadge];
```

To receive remote notifications, you have to implement [parts of the NSApplicationDelegate protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008592-CH1-SW35):

```
- (void)application:(NSApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

Push notifications are only available for apps distributed via the Mac App Store (you have to configure certificates and provisioning for Push notifications to work).

For details, have a look at the Local and [Push Notifications Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW7)

Apple also provides sample code for OS X Push notifications: [Pushy Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/PushyMac/)

Comment: I am extremely sorry, I forgot to update the post last night since shortly after writing the post I found a WWDC 2011 video on push notifications. In there it addressed that, but if an error is returned that I would have to check my entitlements in my provisioning profile. I have been busting my balls over this, since I have configured my certificates to work with push notifications and still this error is returned. Is there a way you and I could setup 5 minutes of each others time just so I can quickly show you my screen and confirm the things I've done? I hope this is possible, only 5 mins!

Comment: PS I've seen your resume on stackoverflow, and saw your website, I am pleased to know that you're a MAC OS X developer! That's super awesome weichsel. I've seen your twitter account and downloaded the app so I could play with it. Super fun, im loving the dashed bezier curver on the node links, the zooming in/out capability and the way you handled the nifty aqua blue banner in normal screen mode to fullscreen mode. Its good to see an experienced person inputting his two cents on this post. I do hope its possible for me to quickly show you my screen. Thanks buddy.

Comment: PSS. I am creating an in-house app for a client's company, and he doesn't wish to distribute his app on the Mac App Store. It's a tailor made solution, involving other hardware such as biometrics so therefor wanted to keep it in-house only. I saw that there was a way to distribute one's application outside of the Mac App Store and still be able to use push notifications right? I cant be expected to poll to my server just because im not distributing through the app store, can I? :(

Comment: AFAIK, Push Notifications are only available to Mac App Store applications. But your scenario sounds like a simple client-server setup. Are both stations in the same network? Maybe you can communicate via Bonjour. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/samplecode/PictureSharing/

Comment: No they're in seperate networks. We also have iPads that would connect to the employee management system where the director can see which employees have walked in late, live too (with the help of push notifications, he'd be notified when the app is closed). Something as simple as this should still be available outside of the app store, no?

Comment: Ok so it seems that it definitely isnt possible after reading the first line itself on this page developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/… This begs the question whether I can distribute it in a MAC enterprise app store like they have for the iOS enterprise store. This allows apps to be distributed internally but still have it managed by Apple. –  Pavan 6 mins ago